# Odd behavior rendering dynamically type of input type checkbox Angular 2+

Tags: angular, checkbox, dynamic, behavior

**Need:**

- Create an input with the type attribute dynamic. Something like this: `<input id="{{ field.id }}" formControlName="{{ field.code }}" type="{{ 
  field.type }}" />`
- Use the above input with "checkbox" dynamic value inside a FormGroup (reactive forms).

**Problem:**

The problem comes when i set the **type** attribute dynamically and what it causes is creating the checkbox in the DOM with an attribute value="false" when i initialize the FormControl with *false*. Therefore the FormGroup never gets updated.

**Notes:**

- The problem does not happens when i set directly **type="checkbox"** because it does not generate the value attribute.
- The behavior is presented in latests versions of Chrome and Firefox.
- The behavior is presented in angular@4.4.6 and angular@5.0.0 (i haven't tested in other versions of Angular)

**Behavior simulation:**
You can check the behavior by yourself on this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-ke3jjn

I really would like to understand if this behavior is normal and why.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing your `FormControl` defined in your `.ts`. Have you seen the Dynamic Form docs? https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: I am using FormBuilder which internally creates the FormControls required. The behavior is the same with FormControl by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an open ticket for that and Igor Minar and Angular team are looking into it:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329

In the meantime you can do this workaround:

```
onChange(event) {   
    this.form.get(event.target.attributes.formcontrolname.value)
    .setValue(event.target.checked);
}
```

And in your html you add this:

```
<input id="check" type="{{'checkbox'}}" formControlName="checkOdd (change)="onChange($event)"/>
```

You can also add conditions inside the onChange to check on the type of the input and do something different with it, something like:

```
onChange(event) {  
    if(event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
      console.log('Checkbox'); 
    }
    if(event.target.type === 'text') {
      console.log('text'); 
    }

    this.form.get(event.target.attributes.formcontrolname.value)
    .setValue(event.target.checked);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-kzunhk?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

This might be another flavor of the same issue. With a model driven form, if you set an input type dynamically to 'email', email validation won't work - not browser or Angular validation. Instead, it gets validated as  text. NgModel and all else works though. Assume field.type==='email':

```
<input *ngFor="field in fields" [type]="field.type" [(ngModel)]="field.model" [required]="field.required"/>
```

I'm almost sure I've done this with some early 4.x and it worked, but can be memory playing tricks with old man. Maybe I used ngSwitch or ngIf to swap the whole inputs instead, which I guess is also the only work-around at the moment.