# Why does a checkbox not work as expected in Angular when I pass the type with bracket notation?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I basically spent hours fixing an issue in a dynamic Angular (reactive) form that uses a checkbox. In the end, I found that setting `<input [type]="'checkbox'">` produces a different and unexpected result, while `<input type="checkbox">` works as expected.

Is this a bug or did I do something wrong? I always thought that the bracket notation lets me pass TypeScript objects within my template, so `[bla]="'foo'"` would be the same as `bla="foo"`.

Here is a minimal example to play around: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqwwby

It would be nice if someone could explain to me why the behavior is different. And maybe other people will find this useful too when working with checkboxes in Angular forms. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a bug :)

Comment: @Vega you are right, I found it thanks to StackOverflow's link function. I probably searched for the wrong keywords with Google before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a limitation of Angular that has been reported as bug (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329), but the issue on GitHub has been closed by the Angular team.

See also the answers here: [Odd behavior rendering dynamically type of input type checkbox Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652294/odd-behavior-rendering-dynamically-type-of-input-type-checkbox-angular-2)

Looks like the best way to handle dynamic input types is by using `*ngIf` surrounding the form element or by implementing a workaround given in the other question linked above.